# FTP client that supports 2 concurrent FTP sessions

Tags: ftp, session

I'm looking for an FTP client that can connect to two different FTP servers at the same time and allow file transfer or synchronization between those two servers. Basically what I want to achieve is to transfer/synchronize files between 2 different sites from my local machine.  Are there any clients around that support this functionality? If there are none, is there an alternative to achieve this?

I've taken a look at net2ftp, a web based FTP client, which provides almost the same functionality that I need. What I'm looking for though is a desktop app. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a Windows [FTP client comparison](http://svhostingblog.com/reviews/picking-the-best-ftp-client-among-filezilla-flashfxp-and-smartftp/) evaluating FileZilla, FlashFXP, and SmartFTP.

Answer (score 2):

If the servers supports it you can use the [File eXchange Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) (FXP).

[FlashFXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlashFXP) supports FXP.

Comment: Correct, but note the *if* -- not all servers support it (or have it disabled)!

Answer (score 2):

**[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)** allows multiple concurrent FTP sessions.

you can sync/compare files and folder and of course copy/move from one server to another.

Totall Commander is shareware, try before you buy.

Answer (score 1):

You should try FTP Expert, best FTP software ever in my opinion.

It seems it is now called [Ace Ftp](http://software.visicommedia.com/en/products/aceftp/features/).

> Conduct server-to-server file transfers
>   Perform local-to-local file transfers
>   Open several FTP sites simultaneously

Comment: This looks pretty neat. Definitely something I would consider if I can't find a free alternative. Thanks a lot Damien.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, there is [SmartFTP](http://www.smartftp.com/). Their [features](http://www.smartftp.com/features/) page lists:

> FXP (Server-To-Server Transfer) support

Answer (score 0):

[Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) (Mac OS only) supports multiple concurrent connections and [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) for direct server-to-server transfer. It has a great UI as well.